# Why is Array.apply() setup resulting in an undefined index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In a constructor, I'm creating a two dimensional array like so:

```
this.grid = Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map((el, i) => {
      return Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map((el, i) => {
        return {
          key1: null,
          key2: null
        };
      });
    });
```

After i `console.log(this.grid)` I get a two-dimensional array with the objects and null properties. however if I try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.grid[0][1]))` there's an undefined error on `[1]`

```js
class Grid {
  constructor() {
    this.grid = Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map((el, i) => {
      return Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map((el, i) => {
        return {
          key1: null,
          key2: null
        };
      });
    });
  }
}
// used in another external class with require() and instantiated like:
let grid = new Grid();

console.log(grid);
console.log(JSON.stringify(grid[0][1]))
```

I understand some differences between constructing arrays with the constructor, and using Array.apply(). Maybe I'm using apply() incorrectly?

I've attempted constructing this array in multiple ways. from a nested for-loop where `.push()`ing the same objects to the second dimension and then each row the grid.

```
this.grid = []
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
      let row = []
      for( let j =0; j< 3; ++j) {
        let obj = {
          key1: "property",
          key2: "property"
        }
        row.push(obj);
      }
      this.grid.push(row);
    }
```

```js
class Grid {
  constructor() {
    this.grid = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      let row = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        let obj = {
          key1: null,
          key2: null
        };
        row.push(obj);
      }
      this.grid.push(row);
    }
  }
 }
 // used in another external class file with a require() and instantiation like so:
 let grid = new Grid();
console.log(JSON.stringify(grid[0][1]));
```

I expect the log to show the object at those respective indices. However, `JSON.stringify(this.grid[0][1])` is still:

`TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

Comment: edited. the example now in the snippet (run in a browser console) reproduces the results noted in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable named `grid` has a *property* named `grid`, which is the outer array containing the inner arrays. So, to reference the inner arrays, access `grid.grid`. Otherwise, just referencing `grid` gives you the instance, not the outer array.

```js
class Grid {
  constructor() {
    this.grid = Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map((el, i) => {
      return Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map((el, i) => {
        return {
          key1: null,
          key2: null
        };
      });
    });
  }
}
// used in another external class with require() and instantiated like:
let grid = new Grid();

console.log(JSON.stringify(grid.grid[0][1]))
```

It might be clearer if the instance had a method on it, like `printGrid` which printed the grid. Then, it would make sense that you would call `grid.printGrid` to print the grid, and you would reference `grid.grid` to get to the outer array (and `grid` itself is clearly just the instance).

To reduce this sort of confusion, you might consider using a different property name, like `outerArray` (or a different class name).

```js
class Grid {
  constructor() {
    this.outerArray = Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map((el, i) => {
      return Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map((el, i) => {
        return {
          key1: null,
          key2: null
        };
      });
    });
  }
}
const gridInstance = new Grid();

console.log(JSON.stringify(gridInstance.outerArray[0][1]))
```